# parsley.js - prevent isValid from firing events / just check true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsley.js

Hello I am at my wit's end and I've been stuck creating a more complex version of the form than the example I provide.

I have JS object that is representation of the form. I use parsley's "isValid" on the form itself (`checkAll` and `checkGroup` function). These methods are fired on every input that is marked with `data-parsley-required` attribute. The reason for this is I need to know the state of the whole form and it's parts so I can enable/disable step buttons.

Everything works fine but I also need to call external API when all validations have successed, see line 35. The methods `checkAll` and `checkGroup` are basically firing the events again, thus making more AJAX calls (we have limit on calls to the API). Is there a way to force method `isValid` to just check if the field has been validated and get true/false value out of it?

The whole thing is coded and depends on this structure so the best way would be to have similar functionality. I'm not so experienced so I make lot of mistakes. My example is very simplified version of my actual form but when you open console window you can see what I mean. Uncomment lines 32 and 33 to see the difference and you will know what I mean.

[Example code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNWwZw?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="myform">
  <div id="section1">
  <input type="text" id="field1" data-parsley-required data-parsley-trigger="input" data-parsley-group="group1" data-parsley-lengthvalidator data-parsley-remote="http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1" data-parsley-remote-validator="remotevalidator" /><br />
  <button id="next" disabled>Next</button><br />
  </div>
  <div id="section2">
  <input type="text" id="field2" data-parsley-required data-parsley-trigger="input" data-parsley-group="group2" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit-button" disabled />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function Form(form) {
  this.form = form;
  this.validations = {};
  this.formValid = false;
  this.checkAll = function() {
    var result = $(form).parsley().isValid();
    if (result) {
      $('#submit-button').removeAttr('disabled');
      console.log('form validated');
    } else {
      $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', true);
    }
   this.formValid = result;
  };
  this.checkGroup = function(e) {
    var group = $(e.target).attr('data-parsley-group');
    var result = $(form).parsley().isValid({group: group});
    if (result) {
      $('#next').removeAttr('disabled');
      console.log('group validated');
    } else {
      $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    this.validations[group] = result;
  };
 this.initialize = function() {
   var self = this;

   $(this.form).parsley();
   $('*[data-parsley-required]').on('input', function(e) {
     self.checkAll();
    self.checkGroup(e);
   });

   $('#field1').parsley().on('field:success', function() {
       console.log('calling another API')
   })

   Parsley.addValidator('lengthvalidator', {
      validateString: function(value) {
        console.log('local validator');
        return value.length > 0;
      }
   });
   Parsley.addAsyncValidator('remotevalidator', function(response) {
      console.log('remote validator');
      return response.responseJSON.name === 'bulbasaur';

     })
   }
  }

 var form = new Form('#myform');
 form.initialize();
```

Comment: You seem to be validating on 'input', which could be very greedy, and also trigger unintended additional validations. Why not trigger validation on click of submit, and only allow it to continue if it passes? This is how I almost always handle validation.

Comment: the client needs it certain way. the form is quite large and multi-step so it allows you to move between forms. i don't have inputs on all of them. but I need to set the JS object somehow but I don't want to trigger the validations, just basically get the result of the validation.

Comment: somehow I thougth `parsley.validate()` performs the validations and `parsley.isValid()` only gets me true/false without performing the validation. am I getting this wrong?